# В google spread sheets не работает SUMIFS (и SUMIF) при использование IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть 2 таблицы в google spread sheets (разными файлами).
При использование в формуле **SUMIFS** (и **SUMIF**), формулы **IMPORTRANGE** в качестве аргумента, получаю *#N/A* (Ошибка В качестве аргумента необходимо указать диапазон ячеек.).

Формула:

```
=SUMIFS(IMPORTRANGE("1X_ivkvR9cUaWKnorx9BiAj3ip4ebFGUdzzYOXpGzpng";"Полная База!E:E");IMPORTRANGE("1X_ivkvR9cUaWKnorx9BiAj3ip4ebFGUdzzYOXpGzpng";"Полная База!C:C");A2)
```

Файлы прилагаю:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X_ivkvR9cUaWKnorx9BiAj3ip4ebFGUdzzYOXpGzpng/edit?usp=sharing - откуда импортируем данные с помощью  IMPORTRANGE

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qyotHAX5gdI15kHlJFZgYBsO9Uqhdl2g3vNOm7S5XZw/edit?usp=sharing - куда импортируем данные с помощью  IMPORTRANGE (ячейка B2).

**Если примеряю IMPORTRANGE без SUMIFS - всё работает.
Почему не работает с SUMIFS?**

Comment: И как Вам помочь, если книга закрыта для редактировния?

Comment: @vikttur спасибо за ответ, можно сюда написать.
Думаю, открывать доступ на редактирование для всех не самый продуктивный способ. Представляете, если 5 человек одновременно будут там ковыряться.

Comment: Представляете, если для помощи Вам каждый из пяти будет создавать две таблицы - одну с данными, в другую переносить Вашу формулу для проверки... Кому надо?!

Comment: @vikttur - убедили, открыл

Answer (score 0):

Ответ уже написан в самом вопросе:

> В качестве аргумента необходимо указать диапазон ячеек.

Действительно, функция IMPORTRANGE возвращает данные типа "массив" (64), что легко проверить, используя функцию [TYPE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267375):

```
=TYPE(IMPORTRANGE("1X_ivkvR9cUaWKnorx9BiAj3ip4ebFGUdzzYOXpGzpng";"Полная База!C:C"))
```

Аргументом [SUMIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496) должен быть *диапазон*, что вовсе не то же самое. Но интересно другое: в той же официальной документации по функциям [сказано](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) дословно:

> Any function that takes a range, such as A1:B6, as an input parameter
> will also accept an array in its place. For example, SPARKLINE takes a range as the first parameter  to specify the values to plot. You can use the array result of IMPORTRANGE as SPARKLINE's input.

Так любая ли функция ведет себя так же, как SPARKLINE? На практике мы видим, что не любая. Проверяем далее: временно запишем в ячейку K1 формулу первого IMPORTRANGE, чтобы сделать промежуточный импорт данных в колонку K. Соответственно изменим основную формулу.

```
=SUMIFS(K1:K100,IMPORTRANGE("1X_ivkvR9cUaWKnorx9BiAj3ip4ebFGUdzzYOXpGzpng";"Полная База!C1:C100"),A2)
```

Такая формула работает! А вот следующая формула, при аналогичном промежуточном импорте в колонку K второго диапазона, - уже не работает.

```
=SUMIFS(IMPORTRANGE("1X_ivkvR9cUaWKnorx9BiAj3ip4ebFGUdzzYOXpGzpng";"Полная База!E1:E100");K1:K100;A2)
```

Таким образом, требование типа данных "диапазон" важно лишь для первого аргумента SUMIFS. Официальная документация умалчивает эти нюансы, так что часто приходится разбираться в деталях опытным путем.